# Compute the Lebesgue integral $\int_D \frac{x-y}{1+x+y} d\mathcal{L}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Compute the Lebesgue integral $\int_D \frac{x-y}{1+x+y} d\mathcal{L}^2$, with $D:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | 0<x+y<1,\, 0<x-y<1\}$, by using the transformation theorem.

---

So far, I haven't found a transformation that simplifies the integral.
In particular, trying polar coordinates doesn't look like a good idea since I don't see a way of making use of the particular properties of $\cos,\,\sin$. How do I continue?

Comment: The obvious transformation is $(u,v)=(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks but how do I show that this is bijective?